# Javascript bookmark when clicked image appears

Tags: javascript

I Want to create a bookmark that when clicked, runs a piece of javascript and adds an image on the page

Can anybody point me in the direction of how to go about doing this?

---

I want to write a script that I can bookmark, so that when its clicked, this image 'http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png' appears on the page

Tried this with no luck

```
javascript:var img=document.createElement('img');img.src='http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png';body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Where the image comes from? What do you mean with bookmark? (button? hyperlink?)

Comment: would appreciate if you can show what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'your path';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

For bookmark, make sure to put `javascript:` before above code and compress it with JS minifier/compresser.

Once compressed, you need to put `javascript:` before it and save in bookmarks/bookmarks toolbar, here is it expressed:

```
javascript:var img=document.createElement("img");img.src="your path";document.body.appendChild(img)
```

Comment: I've tried this with no luck @Sarfraz

javascript:var img=document.createElement('img');img.src='http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png';body.appendChild(img);

Comment: @Liam: Instead of `body.appendChild(img);`, use `document.body.appendChild(img);`

Comment: Thanks @Sarfraz, is it possible to put it in an absolute div and open it up on the page?

Comment: @Liam: Yes, you will have to create one using `createElement` (like in above example for img) and then append it it `body` like above example. To set css, you will have to use `mydiv.style.position = "absolute"`, etc

Comment: Thanks @Sarfraz, do you know where I can go to read about that? Im new sorry